# Creating Azure SQL V12 Full Text Index is very slow

Tags: sql-server, azure, full-text-search

I'm creating a full text index on 7 columns of a 30 million row table.

5 days on this query:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM sys.dm_fts_index_keywords( 5, OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[FormattedAddress]'))
```

Returns 500,000 rows and seems to be slowing.

This database is a standard S2.

Is there anything I can do to speed things up?

Comment: To clarify. It's not the count query that's slow it's creating the index.

Answer (score 1):

A few things you can do are

1. Scale up to higer SKU say P1 and let index build complete
2. Scale down to S2

Please also see resource usage of the database to see if you are hitting any resource limits. You can't turn off the singing as those config options are not available in SQL DB.

Comment: So FTS is not possible on lower SKUs? My first free-test search has a 5-6 seconds lag, then super-fast. If I wait a minute and try again, the first search is slow, again. Its like something is cached in memory for a short while and thrown out again

Comment: Is this a consistent pattern?

Comment: Yes, when I publish to Azure, the first search is slow (5-6 seconds), sub-sequent searches are super fast. If I wait a minute, the first search will be slow. Its very consistent. On my development machine I use SQL server 2014 and I experience no delays with FTS

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! We will look into it and see the ways to improve this experience.

Comment: That would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Lets try a few things.  First lets run the query till it completes.  Second we will want to clean the buffer cache and then rerun the query.  It might also be a problem they said was fixed in 2008.  Check to make sure that the signature verification is turned off.  Also one more thing to check is the memory allocation for FTS.  The FullText service runs independantly from the SQL service, so there's a chance it's starved for memory.